# JNI use in UMDF driver

Tags: java-native-interface, driver, umdf

I have a umdf driver and I would like to call some functions in .jar files to establish a connection between my driver (PCSC Reader) and an eclipse plugin (JCOP).

I called some java functions (from .jar) in a c++ main using JNI but can we write JNI code in a UMDF driver ? 
If yes, I would appreciate some guidelines or point of views about how to approach the subject ...

There aren't much info about the subject when you google it so any info is much appreciated !
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any UMDF driver experience, however, after reading the over view I don't see any reason why JNI would not be able to communicate directly with the Reflector.  I don't think it will be able to communicate with the device stack or manager.  So, if I understand this correctly, you should probably have some driver you load independently of JNI and then use JNI to talk to the driver via the Reflector.

On a more general note, I would recommend keeping your JNI code as simple as possible.  My JNI code usually only functions as a Java <=> Native translation layer.  All of the complexity and processing is done in a backing library that can be run independently of Java.  By doing that, you can debug your native code with gdb or visual studio without having to jump around an already running JVM.  You can choose to either ship the stand alone library as a native dependency and add it the the systems library load path or you can simply link it to the JNI library statically.  I have had very good results using LTO and static linking in that exact scenario.